# php pear: how can i check what files did the package install?

Tags: php, pear

after I installed a package with pear, i would like to know what files this package installed. how can i check that?

thanks

Comment: With all do respect i do not deserve a -1. please read my question carefully!! i want to know where it installed the files and not what packages i have installed!. i could not find that on google! thanks a lot!

Comment: I brought you back to 0. This question helped me haha. Cheers buddy.

Comment: ahah thanks man :) glad it helped ya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the package via the pear installer (for example with "pear install package-name" at the command line), then you just need to do:

```
$ pear list package-name
```

It will also tell you what type of files they are (test scripts, documentation, data etc.)

If the package is from a different channel than pear.php.net, prefix the package name with the channel name and `/`:

```
$ pear list channel-name/package-name
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest just to go to the pear folder and look for the folder of the package you just installed. I don't think pear has a built in utility for this.

@People downvoting. I think you misunderstand. He doesn't want to know what packages he has, he wasn't to know the specific files the packages add.

Comment: pear has a utility for this - see my answer ;-)